# Why JQuery scrollTop() won't work

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have two `divs` and each has two `classes`, **hidden** and **shown** ( the classes are required for the responsive web ).

**HTML**

```
<!-- buttons -->
<div class="jump_to_raspored_busa_sidemenu">Cjenik</div>
<div class="jump_to_cjenik_sidemenu">Raspored</div>

<!-- parts -->
<div class="cjenik shown">Cjenik scroll</div>
<div class="zet_linije hidden">Zet linije</div>
<div class="zet_linije shown">Zet linije</div>
<div class="cjenik hidden">Cjenik scroll</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.jump_to_raspored_busa_sidemenu').on('click',function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.cjenik').offset().top }, 1000);
});

$('.jump_to_cjenik_sidemenu').on('click',function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.zet_linije').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

When I click on the `Cjenik`, the `scrollTop` works fine.
But when I click on the `Raspored`, it doesn't scroll down.

Why it works for the `Cjenik` part, but not fot the `Raspored` part ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34yGK/1/)

Comment: That's because selector `$('.zet_linije')` matches multiple elements.

Comment: start debugging by logging `offset().top` on click and see what it returns? `on('click',function(){ console.log( $('.cjenik').offset().top); ... })`

Comment: @Martin So does `$('.cjenik')` but for it it works.

Comment: It get's the first element in the set of `.zet_linije`, and the offset on that returns `0`. Target the last one, see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/34yGK/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have two elements with that class `.zet_linije` and it is matching on the first one (which is hidden so it has no `offset top`).

I'm using your `.shown` class to target the visible element with the class `.zet_linije`

Try this:

```
$('.jump_to_cjenik_sidemenu').on('click',function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.zet_linije.shown').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/34yGK/5/

**The reason it works for your other one is because if we look at the DOM**:

```
<div class="cjenik shown">Cjenik scroll</div>
<div class="zet_linije hidden">Zet linije</div>
<div class="cjenik hidden">Cjenik scroll</div>
<div class="zet_linije shown">Zet linije</div>
```

The `shown` item is **first** in the DOM for `.cjenik`, so that's getting returned when you simply do `$(".cjenik").offset()` **whereas** for `zet_linije`, the `hidden` one comes first.

Comment: one could also use `$('.zet_linije:visible')`

Comment: @Vucko Because the `shown` item on `.cjenik` is **before** the hidden one in the HTML structure. That isn't the case for the `.zet_linije` one.

Comment: @lordvlad We could, but we might as well use the classes he's already using.

Comment: @mattytommo So the **HTML** was the problem. Silly me. What does `$('.zet_linije.shown')` (selector) mean ? It selects `<div class="zet_linije shown">...` or `<div class="zet_linije><div class="shown">..."` ?

Comment: @Vucko As there's no space, it means an element with **both classes**. So `<div class="zet_linije shown">`

Answer (score 2):

It is working.  jQuery can't tell the difference between the hidden div and the shown div.  You need to animate like this

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.zet_linije.shown').offset().top }, 1000);
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/34yGK/3/

It is working for both links. Just that the .cjenik link comes higher up in the HTML